# How to stop ScrollViewer from scrolling down

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I need to make the ScrollViewer to only scroll down.

I have created a scrollviewer in Xaml and have populated it with a stackpanel full of rectangles in code. I then start the user at the bottom and want them to use a "walking" motion with their fingers (like a bass player) to scroll to the top but do not want them to be able to scroll back to the bottom.

My Xaml looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="730" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="462">
    <StackPanel Name="TrackStackPanel">

    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But since it is filled in code, need to accomplish as much as I can in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try disabling vertical scrolling via `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="disabled"` - handle the gestures, then scroll accordingly by setting [ScrollToVerticalOffset].

If this does not work, try placing a layer (a Grid for example) above your ScrollViewer, so that it will receive all the gestures, then do as above, scroll via ScrollToVerticalOffset.

Comment: I really don't want to take that route, I made an attempt but the UI felt laggy. My solution was to allow the user to go up, but penalize them for it. Thanks for the advice though. :)

Comment: Penalize them? sounds harsh! ;-)